# jQuery datatables customizable columns (asp.net usercontrol)

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, datatables

net webforms application.

In my .aspx page Im using jQuery datatables and its gets data using ajax.

In my jQuery datatables I have some configuration for setting up my columns:

```
'columnDefs': [{
                        'targets': 0,
                        'searchable': false,
                        'orderable': false,
                        'className': 'dt-body-center',
                        'render': function(data, type, full, meta) {
                            //return '<input type="checkbox">';
                            if (data == "false") {
                                return '<input type="checkbox" class="styled green">';
                            } else {
                                return '<input type="checkbox" class="styled green" checked="' + data + '">';
                            }

                        }
                    }],
```

I have a requirement to move this jQuery datatable to an usercontrol so it can be reusable on other parts of the web application but I should be able to let the control know what columns to hide.

I was thinking on sending from server other property in my json, an array maybe named `HideCols` that has the index of the columns that I want to hide and then apply with jQuery some code to hide them.

Im getting the table data like this:

```
"fnServerData": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {

                        aoData.push(
                                { name: "filter", value: filterVal }
                                );

                        $.ajax({
                            "dataType": 'json',
                            "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            "type": "GET",
                            "url": sSource,
                            "data": aoData,
                            "success": function(msg) {


                                // here I get my json table data from server

                                var json = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
                                fnCallback(json);

                                // here I can do my jQuery code to hide columns
                                if(json.HideCols != null)
                                {
                                }

                             }
                          });
                    }
```

Other way would be great if I can send from server the `columnDefs` configuration but I guess its going to be more tricky.

> Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the dynamic columnDefs (colModel) functionality with jqGrid. You may read the post here [jqgrid-dynamic-reading-of-colmodel-and-colnames-from-codebehind-of-aspx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32926017/5104101)

You may get the basic idea of generating dynamic columnDefs (xxx_colModel in above post) and ajaxData (xxx_Data in above post) from code-behind and implement it in your way. Set properties of columns to hide in the dynamically generated columnDefs.

As regard to your approach of hiding the columns:

> I was thinking on sending from server other property in my json, an array maybe named HideCols that has the index of the columns that I want to hide and then apply with jQuery some code to hide them.

You may add another property to top level of JSON along with xxx_colModel and xxx_Data say xxx_HiddenCols and store csv column IDs e.g. 2,8,9
Then on the client side, after the grid is initialized, you may use for loop to process each column to hide e.g.

```
var colArray = xxx_HiddenCols.split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < colArray.length; i++) {
    table.column( colArray[i] ).visible( false );
}
```