# Getting the dataset in Json instead of Xml ASP.NET Web service

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, datatable, webmethod

I am still new to asp.net, and I am currently trying to create a web-service that will get the data from my SQL database in order to display it in an android application.

I am able now to get the data I want from the SQL procedure (that gets customer information) and the response is in XML.

I have searched a lot about a good tutorial showing how to get the response in JSON instead of XML with no luck (also tried some answers I found here on stack overflow) but very less were about dataset.

here is the code I have so far, any help will be appreciated .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace ART
{    
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        SqlCommand cmdselect = null, cmdinserted;
        SqlConnection con4, converiler, con3, con;
        SqlDataAdapter da4, da, da3;
        SqlDataReader dr;    

        [WebMethod]         
        public DataSet AboneKullanici(int pkAbone)
        {    
            SqlConnection conFriends = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TTL;Integrated Security=True;");
            DataSet dsvrs = new DataSet();
            cmdselect = new SqlCommand();
            cmdselect.CommandText = "spAboneKullanici";
            cmdselect.CommandTimeout = 0;
            cmdselect.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmdselect.Connection = conFriends;
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdselect);
            cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@aboneid", SqlDbType.Int, 10).Value = pkAbone;
            conFriends.Open();
            da.Fill(dsvrs, "kullaniclar");
            conFriends.Close();
            return dsvrs;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way

- Set function descriptors to return JSON
- Query your data into a `DataTable`
- Convert your `DataTable` to `Dictionary`
- Serialize the `Dictionary` to `JSON`

That's it

```
[WebMethod()]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string AboneKullanici(int pkAbone) {
    SqlConnection conFriends = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TTL;Integrated Security=True;");
    DataTable dsvrs = new DataTable("kullaniclar");
    cmdselect = new SqlCommand();
    cmdselect.CommandText = "spAboneKullanici";
    cmdselect.CommandTimeout = 0;
    cmdselect.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmdselect.Connection = conFriends;
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdselect);
    cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@aboneid", SqlDbType.Int, 10).Value = pkAbone;
    conFriends.Open();
    da.Fill(dsvrs);
    conFriends.Close();

    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> row;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dsvrs.Rows) {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn col in dsvrs.Columns) {
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
        rows.Add(row);
    }
    return serializer.Serialize(rows);
}
```

Comment: Since you are new to asp.net, might I suggest you look at web api. The web service technique you have used is outdated. If all you need is json, then just use web api.

Comment: @Don could you please give some links which i can take a look at what you have suggested  ( and i knew it was out dated but my professor insisted to use this way since this is the way he got used to )

Comment: @96ASP43 It was a small typo check updated code `foreach (DataColumn col in dsvrs.Columns) {`

Comment: Just go onto asp.net website and check out web api or check this link, http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: @haraman thanks alot for your help you have made my day i swear ,

Comment: @Don You suggestion is good, APIs are much more better than web services, but a lot depends on OP's requirements where (s)he has to use it, config of server, version of VS, .NET Framework etc...

Comment: @haraman Id on't understand why you are putting all data rows into a dictionary when you can simply get an array of data rows by doing `DataTable.Rows`? See my answer.

Comment: @kyaqb Yes it can be but consider some scenario where you would not directly want to serialize a DataTable you may need some manipulation with the data, headers, concatenation of fields etc. as an example you can check my this post on SO http://stackoverflow.com/a/32926017/5104101

Comment: @haraman First you are not serializing a data table. `DataTable.Rows` returns an array of `DataRow`, this is what you serialize. Secondly, if you need to manipulate the data in your data table, you simply do this before getting the array of data rows and serializing them. And lastly, with respect to this question, my solution is much simpler than yours.

Comment: @kyaqb You are right your solution is simpler but approach and implementation largely depends on the requirements of user where mine may be better suited. Some conditional data manipulations may not be applied to the datatable directly or the user may not just need the datatable in the serialized output as in my given example.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this (VB.Net):

```
'dt is the data table with your data
Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer
Return js.Serialize(dt.Rows)
```